# Add-PSSnapin cannot be loaded. A type mismatch happened

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I am just trying to run SharePoint 2010 Management Shell, but it throws an error.

```
Add-PSSnapin : Could not load type 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPActionLinkType' 

from assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, 

PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' due to value type mismatch.At 

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\CONFIG\POWERSHELL\Registration\SharePoint.ps1:3 

char:13+ Add-PsSnapin <<<<  Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell    + CategoryInfo  

        : NotSpecified: (:) [Add-PSSnapin], TypeLoadExcept   ion 

   + FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.TypeLoadException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Co   mmands.AddPSSnapinCommand
```

I have no clue what could cause the type mismatch other than having Visual Studio 2015 enterprise in the machine.

Anyone knows why?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you are talking about loading SharePoint Commandline from normal PowerShell commandline  Add-PSSnapin with Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell as the argument....

The most likely reason is that some how you are running under x86 powershell, which makes the x64 .dlls incompatible.

You can try to check $pshost to see whether the path is to the x86 or the x64 version of PowerShell:

> $pshome   # if x64 you will see:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0

> $pshome  #if x86 host only you will see:

C:\Windows\SysWOW64\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0
```

Comment: I think you can try to repair by changing the path of the short cut if you are getting this straight out of the gate from the default SharePoint Commandline Shortcut

Comment: It's running in x64. :)

Comment: $psversiontable will tell you what version of PowerShell is running....I'm not sure that the SharePoint 2010 snapin is compatible with 2.0+ versions (think it was just 2.0)...so ...Might be other avenue to test, starting under 2.0 is you have a newer version installed. Otherwise, I'm stumped, maybe psconfig would help.

Comment: -version 2 argument to PowerShell if running PS 4.